# How to create a new column based on calculations from different groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I am new to R and I am having issues creating a new column with values derived from a specific set of instructions. My dataframe, called `labdata_wide` looks like:

[image: Sample data]

There are a total of 51 rows, one for each participant, and 5 columns (`participant`, `group`, `baseline`, `week 4`, and `week 8`). I would like to create another column called `change` that after checking the participants `group` (i.e. if participants is group A or B), then carries out 1 of 2 possible subtraction calculations.

I would like group A participants to have their *baseline* values subtracted from their *week 4* values AND for group B participants to have their *week 4* values subtracted from their *week 8* values.

> Group A -> *week 4* - *baseline*
>
> Group B -> *week 8* - *week 4*

The calculated values would all have to be in the same column. Would it be possible to do this?

I've tried playing around with the `dplyr` package, specifically the mutate function but I have not been able to figure out how to approach the problem.

The code that I have tried is:

```
labdata_wide %>% group_by(group) %>%  mutate(change = week 4[group == 'A'] - baseline[group == 'A'])
```

But I get the error code:

```
Error: Column "change" must be length 24 (the group size) or one, not 0
```

The stranger issue is that even though I specified what group (i.e. A), I believe it is using group B values because in my df there are 27 group A members and 24 group B members.

Comment: I am also new to Stack Overflow and I tried inserting an image of my df but Stack Overflow created a link for it instead. The link doesn't seem to be in my question. This is the link: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiMue.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be this approach meet your goal. I have not tested it yet as I don't have the data.

```
library(dplyr)

labdata_wide %>%
  mutate(change = case_when(
                  group == "A" ~ `week 4` - baseline,
                  group == "B" ~ `week 8` - `week 4`,
                  TRUE ~ other value/calculation ) )

# or if only group A & B, simply

labdata_wide %>%
  mutate(change = case_when(
                  group == "A" ~ `week 4` - baseline,
                  group == "B" ~ `week 8` - `week 4`))
```

PS. You might want to change your columns name with the proper naming (eg. without space)

Comment: Thank you, nurandi! I've been struggling with this for a while now. I ran the code and got back an error message in regards to the NA values but I changing TRUE ~ NA to TRUE ~ NA_integer_